# Passing 2d array by ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have an 2d array, with name data_forms, now i need to pass this array as object to row.php... how i can do that?

in row.php Im try to print `print_r($_POST);` and output is undefind, also if i try

`print_r(json_decode($_POST));` this will give me Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string

```
$(".saveNewRow").click(function(){
    var number_of_row_and_clmn = parseInt($(".row_count_value").val());
    var data_forms = new Array();
    // all lenght are equal so we used just one 
    var array_2d_length = $('.row-font-style-1 .form-1').length;
    for(var i = 0; i< number_of_row_and_clmn; i++){
        data_forms[i] = new Array();
        if($(".row-font-style-"+i).hasClass("its_div")){
            data_forms[i][0] = "div";
        }else{
            data_forms[i][0] = "tr";
        }
        for(var j = 1; j <= array_2d_length; j++){
           data_forms[i][j] = $(".row-font-style-"+(i+1)+" .field-"+(j-1)).val();
        }
    }
    $.ajax ({ 
        url:"row.php",
        type:"post",
        data:data_forms,
        dataType:JSON,
        statusCode:{
        404:function(){
            $("#output_data").html("page not found!!");
        }},
        success:function (data) {
            $("#output_data").html(data);
        },
        complete:function(){
        }
    });
});
```

thanks for help

**Im found a problem, 
Im change this** `data:data_forms` to data:{mydata: data_forms}
**also Im remove** dataType:JSON

**after im do that, ajax page work fine ... thanks alot for all**

Comment: Did you check what is sended to the back? Place a `console.log(data_forms);` before the ajax call to check what is sended.

Comment: change `dataType:JSON,` to `dataType:'JSON',`

Comment: Sven, yes mate,

the result is true..like this
[Array[21], Array[21], Array[21], Array[21], Array[21]] 

hjpotter92, Im do it now mate, and not work too ... its not print any thing ..

thanks all for help , any idea ..

Comment: Thanks all, 

Im find where is problem ?!! 

Im do it to forms_data 
data:{mydata: data_forms}
and Im remove dataType: JSON ..

All is work fine .. thanks a lot